# USB-stick doesn't react after data backup

Tags: hard-drive, virus

My parents had an old windows-pc which got really slow over time. After booting up, the hard-drive was really loud and sometimes gave an error message, that the hard-drive should be checked, came up. So my conclusion was, that the hard-drive is going to die.

To save some data on the pc (because I couldn't really start windows anymore, it was to slow and hanged up every time), I booted the pc from an ubuntu-live usb-stick. From there I accessed the hard-drive and copied some of the data to another usb-stick. To go more in detail, searching around at the hard-drive, looking at some documents and pictures, went really smooth.

Transferring the data from the (maybe) broken hard-drive to the usb-stick took very long. It was like 500 MB of data and copied almost 3 days.

So, now I have the data on this second usb-stick and I wanted to transfer the data on this usb-stick to another pc and now it gets strange.

After inserting the usb-stick into a windows-pc (tested on 2 computers) the pc reacts really slow. Explorer opening is slow and clicking on the usb-stick didn't work. Windows Explorer did show the usb-drive but not the common storage information (total storage and how much is used).

This behavior was very strange, the usb-stick worked before copying the data. Now I can't access the data anymore and the usb-stick seems to be "dead", too.

What could have happened in this scenario? I know that I did not provide any technical details and it's only a behavioral description. At first I thought maybe there is a virus (or similar) on the old hard-drive which then was copied to the usb-stick which is now slowing down the usb-stick? If this would be true, how can I find out? I don't want to copy the data on the usb-stick to other hard-drives, because maybe they get slow and break, too.

Or could it be something else?

Comment: Do you know what filesystem you used on the second USB-stick that holds the data? was it `ext3`, `FAT32` or something else?

Comment: The behavior within Windows makes sense, since Windows is continuously reading and writing data to the disk, this was not happening in the Linux environment.  However, once you attempted to read the data, Linux also encountered I/O errors.  Since both Windows and Linux are designed to recover from I/O errors they attempted to read the data.  This continuously failed hence the reason it took 3 days to read 500 MB worth of data. The HDD was indeed starting to fail.  As to the way the flash media is causing a similar problem, you have failed to provide, information required to determine the cause